# removing and replacing strings in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, str-replace

I have created a string that allows the user to write 5 names. These names store and then prints out. Then the user gets a question about changing one of those 5 names and after changing, new names prints out. I want to ask the user if he/she wants to replace/change any names and if yes then how many?

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            string[] namn = new string[5];
            Console.Write("Write your 5 names:\n "); 

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                string ad = Console.ReadLine();
                namn[i] = ad;
                Console.WriteLine("Ur names are: " + namn[i]);

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Which name do u like to change (alt 1 to 5: ");  

            int tal = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (tal)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine(" Write a new name: ");
                    Console.ReadLine();

                    break;
            }
            namn[tal - 1] = Console.ReadLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ur new names are: " + namn[i]);
            }

        }


        } }
```

Comment: Why aren't you using an array?
It would allow you to keep the information organized. you don't need to partially edit a string, you need to fully replace a name.

Comment: I have used array at the beginning             string[] namn = new string[5];

Comment: Sorry, didn't saw it.
I might don't understand what the problem is, what you are unable to achieve?

Comment: //I have created an array string that allows the user to write 5 names. These names store and then prints out. Then the user gets a question about changing one of those 5 names and after changing, new names prints out.I want the user to be able to change/replace more than one name and after changing, new name ger printed out

Comment: You can just extract the code that handles the user input and change into a separate function and then executing it inside a loop until the users select a specific option (e.g exit - 6) or just exists the program.

Comment: i can just change one name and not more.

Answer (score 0):

See how this works for you.

1. Cover the entire thing in `while` loop so that it keeps going over the question of which you want to change, insert or delete until you dont want to anymore.
2. Use a list to expand or shrink it (instead of hard coding 5). You can use a condition as well to ensure it doesnt go over 5 in list.

```
    List<string> namn = new List<string>();
    Console.Write("Write your 5 names:\n");
    while (namn.Count != 5)
    {
        Console.Write($"Enter Name [{namn.Count + 1}/5]: ");
        namn.Add(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    while (true)
    {
        int index = 1;
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine($"Your names are: ");
        namn.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{index++} - {x}"));

        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\nWhat would you like to do: ");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Change Name");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Delete Name");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Insert Name");
        Console.WriteLine("anyKey. Exit.\n");

        Console.Write("Selection: ");
        int tal = 0;
        try { tal = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); } catch { continue; }
        switch (tal)
        {
            case 1:
                if (namn.Count == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Nothing to change, insert more then change... press enter to continue");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                }

                Console.Write($"Which name do you want to change [index from 1 to {namn.Count}]: ");
                int updateIndex = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) - 1;
                if (updateIndex < 0 && updateIndex > namn.Count)
                    Console.WriteLine("Nope, must be between the indecies.");
                else
                    Console.Write($"Enter New Name for [{namn[updateIndex]}]: ");
                namn[updateIndex] = Console.ReadLine();
                break;

            case 2:
                if (namn.Count == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Nothing to delete... press enter to continue");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                }

                Console.Write($"Which name do you want to delete [index from 1 to {namn.Count}]: ");
                int deleteIndex = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) - 1;
                if (deleteIndex > namn.Count() && deleteIndex < 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, must be one of these names.");
                else
                    namn.RemoveAt(deleteIndex);
                break;

            case 3:
                Console.Write("Enter Name to insert: ");
                namn.Add(Console.ReadLine());
                break;

            case 4:
                return;
        }
    }
```